# React render input with default value in separate function to display errors

Tags: reactjs

How can the input be rendered in separate function with initial value?

```
import {Field, reduxForm} from "redux-form";

class Com extends React.Component {
   renderInput = ({input, type, placeholder, initial_value, meta}) => {
        
   };
        
   render() {
      return (
          <form action="" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>             
              <Field type="text" name="first_name" component={this.renderInput()} 
               placeholder="" initial_value=""/>
          </form>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Based on your description, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish. Could you please provide a larger context and, if possible, supply a sandbox link?

Comment: Are you just wondering how to render `<Field type="text" name="first_name" component={this.renderInput()} placeholder="" initial_value=""/>` in a separate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function/component with input tag and pass the props that you want in your input fields like type, placeholder, name, id etc.. and render that function with passing the attributes like given below

```
const Field = (name, id, placeholder, ...resProps) => {
   return <input name={name} id={id} placeholder={placeholder} {...resProps} />
}
```

and then render the `Field` component as below

```
class Com extends React.Component {
render() {
   return (
      <form action="" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>             
          <Field type="text" name="first_name" id="id" placeholder=""/>
      </form>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: What's about initial value for the input?

Comment: You can add initial value for value parameter and for changing the value you pass a function to `Field` to change it.